# Android coroutine viewmodelscope cancel

Tags: android, viewmodel, coroutine

I have seen a lot of examples that use a job as a way to cancel coroutines when viewmodel is destroyed.

```
class SetupViewModel : ViewModel() {

    private val completableJob = Job()
    private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + completableJob)

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        completableJob.cancel()
    }
}
```

The strange thing for me is no one seems to be using coroutineScope to do that. I think that should be easier and has less code. Any idea?

```
class SetupViewModel : ViewModel() {
    private val coroutineScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO)

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        coroutineScope.cancel()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Easy way you can use `lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx` and use `viewModelScope` already defined by library and you don't need override `onCleared`, read more [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines)

Comment: Yes, I do know that one. But when in other case, how do you cancel coroutines then? Job.cancel() or coroutineScope.cancel()? I'm trying to find the best practice.

Comment: After I read implementation of `viewModelScope` I think you can use coroutineScope.cancel()

Comment: You are right, so weird that everyone is just copying around while it actually can be simpler

Comment: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/cancellation-in-coroutines-aa6b90163629 take a look here, I think we only need job.cancel() when we need to cancel specify the job.

Comment: The trick is that people use the `cancelAllChildren` thing because once you call `.cancel()` on a scope, it's a final and irreversible thing.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your way of approach is actually correct. What is the exact problem?

Comment: Im trying to find the best practice, but all the tutorials that I have seen use job to cancel coroutines whereas coroutineScope can do it for us. I don't understand why all examples don't use that.